# 60% heignt in div on wordpress site not working?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, height

I am building my own Wordpress theme but i can not get one function to work.

you can se the demo here: [www.jonasolaussen.se/hairdesign/wordpress](http://www.jonasolaussen.se/hairdesign/wordpress)

The big picture can disappears when i set the height to 60%,80% or 100%. It must be 
an px width.

The problem is that i want to have the div at 60% so the site works great on big and small screen resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `height: 100%` to html and body in your main CSS. After that you will be able to set height in percent to the DIV element.

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/yZV2m/1/

Check updated demo and try adding 'clearfix' class to the DIV which is standing at 0px height.

Comment: I can no get to work even with 100% in height, the div collapses totally with 0px in height.

Comment: @user1423248 check updated demo and try adding 'clearfix' class to the DIV which is collapsing to 0px height. Don't forget to copy clearfix css

Comment: Nothing seems to change with the clearfix,

I can not get my head around this problem, maybe i will need to use some sort of responsive webdesign to solve this problem.

Comment: I missspelld height to weight... But it is working now. 

Thanks!